# How to customized fieds in moodle forms?

Tags: moodle, moodle-api

I want to customize moodle course/edit_form.php file and add some more fields and remove some existing fields. Is this possible to do without changing core files?

I followed this article but didn't find anything helpful https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Form_API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a plugin that has a form which saves extra information about the courses and then you can show those fields by overriding the course renderer in the theme.